# TeamCity NetCore 'dotnet restore' Error Value cannot be null

Tags: teamcity, .net-core, dotnet-restore

I'm attempting to build and deploy a netcore app for the first time with TeamCity.  I followed the guide from https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/teamcity-dotnet-core/

I'm running into an issue where TeamCity returns a 'Exit code 1." error at the beginning of the first build step. (a dotnet restore) step.

In the build logs it says the following.

```
Step 1/3: .NET Core (dotnet)
[15:33:58][Step 1/3] Starting: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore src/ProjectFolder
[15:33:58][Step 1/3] in directory:  E:\TeamCity\buildAgent3\work\1151efaecddc7512
[15:33:58][Step 1/3] error: Value cannot be null.
[15:33:58][Step 1/3] error: Parameter name: path1
[15:33:58][Step 1/3] Process exited with code 1
[15:33:58][Step 1/3] Step .NET Core (dotnet) failed
```

I have tried reinstalling the NetCore sdk on my build agents. Among other things.  Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Current dotnet version is 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177.

Comment: Could you provide an image of your dotnet restore build step with advanced settings open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by going to the build configuration and added a parameter `env.HOME`with value `/home/core`(user home directory) then the `dotnet restore` worked.

Sure, it's an ugly workaround just to get by.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it related to unset HOME environment variable, as described here? https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3530

If so, then maybe try upgrading dotnet to preview3.

Comment: Any idea what the HOME environment variable should be set to?  I set DOTNET_HOME to C:\Program Files\dotnet.  PATH is being used by a Java install already ppointing elsewhere.  I don't have my HOME environment variable set, but don't know what to set it to.

Comment: I'll add that when I run 'dotnet restore' locally on my build server from command line, it works.  it is when the TeamCity Agent attempts to run dotnet restore that this error occurs.  The user profile for the TeamCity Agent has Administrator privileges.